Sequelize: missing FROM-clause entry for table
I'm using Sequelize to make a pagination query with QuizModel. My query will include 2 models QuizCategoryModel, QuizInfoModel. My where condition in parent model (QuizModel) includes a reference to
attribute question of QuizInfoModel:
this.quizModel.findAll({
  limit,
  offset,
  where: {
    ...(search && {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          "$quiz_infos.question$": {
            [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`,
          },
        },
        !Number.isNaN(search) && {
          prefix_id: this.sequelize.where(
            this.sequelize.cast(
              this.sequelize.col("quizs.prefix_id"),
              "varchar"
            ),
            {
              [Op.iLike]: search ? `${Number(search)}%` : "%%",
            }
          ),
        },
      ],
    }),
  },
  include: [
    {
      model: QuizCategoryModel,
      attributes: {
        exclude: ["description"],
      },
    },
    {
      model: QuizInfoModel,
      where: { ...quizInfoFilter },
      required: !!quizInfoFilter,
    },
  ],
  order,
});

Using the above code gives me missing FROM-clause entry for table 'quiz_infos'. After researching, I know I can use subQuery to avoid the error but this will return incorrect number of data, i.e: If I set limit to 10, the return data might be 9 instead.
So is there a way to make my query correct but can still avoid using subQuery all together?

Using a DBAL is supposed to make your code easier to understand and maintain. Are you sure that the code you shared is more readable than its SQL counterpart?

Also, what is the difference between Quizz and QuizzInfo in your conceptual model?

Please add model associations in the post

I solved the problem by bringing the query down to the included model instead of using it on the parent where query. So the query will become:
this.quizModel.findAll({
  limit,
  offset,
  include: [
    {
      model: QuizCategoryModel,
      attributes: {
        exclude: ["description"],
      },
    },
    {
      model: QuizInfoModel,
      where: {
        ...quizInfoFilter,
        ...(search && {
          [Op.or]: [
            {
              question: {
                [Op.iLike]: `%${search}%`,
              },
            },
            !Number.isNaN(search) && {
              "$quizs.prefix_id": this.sequelize.where(
                this.sequelize.cast(
                  this.sequelize.col("quizs.prefix_id"),
                  "varchar"
                ),
                {
                  [Op.iLike]: search ? `${Number(search)}%` : "%%",
                }
              ),
            },
          ],
        }),
      },
      required: !!quizInfoFilter,
    },
  ],
  order,
});

